# Error : The type com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage$Builder cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: android

when I use market API(**androidmarketapi-0.6.jar**).It's showing me error on below code.

**Code**

```
String query = "maps";
                AppsRequest appsRequest = AppsRequest.newBuilder()
                        .setQuery(query).setStartIndex(0).setEntriesCount(10)
                        .setWithExtendedInfo(true).build();
```

**Error**

> The type com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage$Builder cannot be
>   resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

**screen shot**

[image]

I had try clean project many times but error is not solve.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means: "A class that you use needs another class that is not on the classpath." You should make sure to add the required jar to the classpath.

EDIT:

You do not need to do anything specific for this. Since you mentioned that you are using Android Play, the update notification is taken care of by Google Play.

You need to just update the **APK** with higher `versionCode` and Google Play should do the rest.

**BUT MAKE SURE:**

- Notifications in Google Play - Settings is ticked.
- Background date in your phone Settings - Accounts and sync is
     ticked.

Comment: which other jar i need you know?

Comment: jars **androidmarketapi-0.6.jar** and **protobuf-java-2.2.0.jar**

Comment: In my case everything works fine with this two jars.

Comment: Thanks for last help , Now i want to find if new update available for my installed app from google play. How's this possible ? Please suggest me if you have any idea about this. Thanks again.